# wpf datagrid cell style change accordingly value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, cell

When I change a value in `wpf datagrid` and my function (save db) gives `true` or `false` back, I want to change the style (`true` = backcolor cell green otherwise red).

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to create a binding from the cells "Background" to the boolean value. Then use a converter to specifiy which color you want to return, depending on "true" or "false". You can access the cell style for example like this: <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" > <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Result, Converter...}"</Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>

Comment: Do you have a little sample? My problems are binding and converter - how to

Comment: There are lots of examples online, for example here http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html.